# How do I get Electorate badge

Tags: discussion

It is hard for me to understand what to do to get this badge maybe because English is not my mother tongue language.

The definition is :"Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions"

Could you explain please.

Thank you

Comment: @animuson this question is not a duplicate, the guy needs clarification for the statement he has here!

Comment: @user689 And it *is* clarified there. He just needs to scroll to the Electorate badge.

Comment: @animuson you didn't read my question. I don't understand the explication "Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions"

Comment: @Lorenzo So go read the Electorate explanation on the duplicate? It is *not* the same thing. Completely different text - there's a lot of information there. Us answering your question here is just going to be us copy-pasting what is there.